# Python Dictonary - Two Files - Multiply the values/attribute based on key value

Tags: python

I have been trying to solve the problem for my friend. However, it seems to bug me as I am unable to map the key values from two files.

Problem description:

First file (sales.txt) has contents:

```
Apple 30
Grape 90
Cup 35
Toy 100
Apple 50
Grape 51
Toy 83
```

Second file (price.txt) has contents:

```
Apple 1.3
Grape 0.99
Cup 1.5
Toy 15
```

The job is to print the total price. In this instance, we need to print 3041.09.

I know for a fact that we need to use dictionaries and to map two dictionaries based on key(s). Hence I have written code as per my knowledge. (Extremely sorry if it is stupid!)

```
f = "sales.txt"
d={}
for line in open(f):
    a=line.split()
    key, values = str(a[0]), int(a[1])
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(int(values))
print(d)

d = dict((key, sum(values)) for key, values in d.items())

print(d)

g = "price.txt"
dy={}
for line in open(g):
    b=line.split()
    unit, price = str(b[0]), float(b[1])
    dy.setdefault(unit, []).append(float(price))
print(dy)

total = 1.0

for i in range(0, len(d)):
    if d[key] == dy[unit]:
        total = d.values*dy.price

print(total)
```

Problem occurs at if condition as it is not getting into the loop. Corrections?

Comment: in the last for loop, you never update the `key` or `unit`.

Comment: Can you explain me briefly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simplified somewhat using a running count in the first loop and just summing the total in the second loop:

```
with open("sales.txt") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split()
        d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + int(value)

with open("price.txt") as g:
    total = sum(d[key] * float(price) for line in g for key, price in [line.split()])
print(total)
#3041.09
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run your code but it seems when you're doing:

```
dy.setdefault(unit, []).append(float(price))
```

you are adding to the key an array instead of a scalar -> like Apple: [1.3] instead of Apple: 1.3

Then at the last loop, do something like

```
for item,count in d.items():
    total += count*dy[item]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
total = 1.0

for i in range(0, len(d)):
    if d[key] == dy[unit]:
        total = d.values*dy.price
```

Use:

```
# the total should start at 0.
total = 0.0

for k in d:
    total = total + d[k]*dy[k]
```

this will iterate over all of the keys in `d` and grab the quantity and price, multiply them and update the total.